# Mysql subquery error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with 100 fields,  I'm having a problem with calculating the moy of students.

I have a problem when using my query i have the same value for all rows . The query is

```
select
      stdt.num as num,
      stdt.nom as nom,
      (select
         (distinct moy_id)
       from stdt,
         dept,
         clas,
         moy
       where clas.class_id = moy.class_id
           and dept.dept_id = stdt.deptid
           and moy.value < 10
           and moy.value <> 0) as moy,
 (select
         (distinct moy_id)
       from stdt,
         dept,
         clas,
         moy
       where clas.class_id = moy.class_id
           and dept.dept_id = stdt.deptid
           and moy.value <> 10
           and moy.value < 4) as moysports

    from stdt,
      dept,
      clas,
      moy
    where clas.classid = moy.classid
        and clas.classid = stdt.clasid
        and stdt.stdtid = dept.stdtid
    group by stdt.num
```

the calcul and the conditions are more complicated than this simple exemple : i have 9 subqueries

### i have the result

jim 14
ana 14
john 14 
mark 14
the result should be :
jim 13 
ana 11
mark 12.5

Comment: You haven't shown an update query there.

Comment: ...nor the actual error.

Comment: sory it's for another post here is a select query

Comment: So what is the problem with your query?

Comment: i edited the text it's ok

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this question isn't practically answerable.

Comment: the problem that i have the same moy for all the students,and it's not true

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select  
>   stdt.num as num,
>   stdt.nom as nom,
>   (select
>      (distinct moy_id)
>    from stdt,
>      dept,
>      clas,
>      moy
>    where clas.class_id = moy.class_id
>        and dept.dept_id = stdt.deptid
>        and moy.value < 10
>        and moy.value <> 0) as moy
> ```

Here moy is computed independently of num and nom.

Try this instead :

```
select
  stdt.num as num,
  stdt.nom as nom,
  moy_id as moy
from stdt,
  dept,
  clas,
  moy
where clas.classid = moy.classid
    and clas.classid = stdt.clasid
    and stdt.stdtid = dept.stdtid
    and moy.value between 1 and 10
```

I could not understand why you wanted to group there, so i just dropped it there. Up to you to add it again.

Comment: i computed num and nom independently because i have others things to calculate with another subquery, using athors conditions

Comment: If you want different moy results, then that means that your "moy" is depending on num and nom, thus you should be able to join moy and stdt without subquery

Comment: no the moy is of course for the name (nom) of student and this same student have a num so i want for such student calculate different moy like the query that i edit it now

Comment: I'm still pretty sure that you don't need subqueries there mate. What your are doing in your original query is just getting the same record of the table moy for every record of the table stdt. Try to give a look @thorsten-kettner answer, which takes care of stdt in subquery.

Comment: i try @thorsten kettner answer i have the same result it's not fine

Comment: If the moy table contains a stdtid, try to change the line moy.classid = stdt.classid by moy.stdtid = stdt.id.
If these fields don't exist, please add your db schema to your question

Answer (score 0):

What do you join dept for? What do you join clas for? In case there is more then one matching moy_id for a student, which one do you want to show? The min or max or a group_concat? Here is the statement simplified.

```
select
  stdt.num as num,
  stdt.nom as nom,
  min
  ((
    select moy_id
    from moy
    where moy.classid = stdt.classid
    and moy.value < 10
    and moy.value <> 0
  )) as moy_id
from stdt;
```